# What is an "additional channel dimension" contain in batch normalization?

Tags: pytorch, batch-normalization, channel

Consider the following explanations regarding batch normalization layers in PyTorch

#1: [one dimensional batch normalization](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm1d.html)

> class torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(.........)
>
> Applies Batch Normalization over a 2D or 3D input (a mini-batch of 1D
> inputs with **optional additional channel dimension**)............

#2: [Second dimensional batch normalization](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html)

> class torch.nn.BatchNorm2d(..........)
>
> Applies Batch Normalization over a 4D input (a mini-batch of 2D inputs with **additional channel dimension**)

#3: [Third dimensional batch normalization](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm3d.html)

> class torch.nn.BatchNorm3d(..............)
>
> Applies Batch Normalization over a 5D input (a mini-batch of 3D inputs with **additional channel dimension**)

All these say that there can be an extra element to each vector undergoing batch normalization and is related to **channel**.

Is the channel referred here is same as the channels of the image? If yes, then what does it contain? Does it contain the number of channels in that particular layer?

Else, what does this additional channel contain?.